# Change background image with a button w/ jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, background

I want to change the background image on the div "content1" when i click on a button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("content1").css("background-image", "url(../images/light.png)");
  });
});

.content1 {
  background-image: url('../images/dark.png');
}
```

My css is external.

Thankyou.

Comment: `$(".content1")` , you missed the `.`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your content is a class. so you need to use jquery selected properly.

```
 $(".content1").css("background-image", "url(../images/light.png)");
```

Comment: Thanks, how could i turn this into a toggle button?